# defining and assigning list of strings using inline statement

Tags: c#, .net

If I have property Keywords which is defined as list of strings

```
public List<string> Keywords;
```

I tried with following inline command to assign new list of string

```
 Keywords =  new List<string>().Add(new List<string>() { "lorem", "ipsum", "root page"})
```

I know that I can use

```
List<string> words = new List<string>() { "lorem", "ipsum", "root page"}; 
Keywords = new List<string>().AddRange(words);
```

but question is how can this be done using inline statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public List<string> Keywords = new List<string>(){"lorem", "ipsum", "root page"};
```

Comment: nice, `()` are not necessary

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `Add()` method of List.

```
  List<string> Keywords = new List<string>(){"lorem", "ipsum", "root page"};
```